# Advantages of using Passenger + Apache over Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, mongrel, production, webrick

I want to convince my management that using Apache + passenger setup is way to go on production rather than  having webrick or mongrel

I have found some points from the net.

It would be great help if you could add your thoughts as that will defiantly help me to present my points. (technical details are welcome)

and It will great if you could send some links if you have any

thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Comment: What are your speed/scaling requirements? Do you suffer performance problems? Is your deployment strategy too painful? What do you expect to improve when switching to passenger? Why are you currently dissatisfied with Webrick/Mongrel?

Comment: hi @matt Yes, its all about speed and scale, Coz in this system its pulling out some 5 years of data currently so performance and and future scalability is the main concern and in future site is planning to have full SSL support as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see the [comparison](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/comparisons.html) and make your choice

```
Overall conclusion
Participant                                      Speed (r/sec)  Memory usage (MB)
Apache (prefork MPM) + Phusion Passenger         444.88         240.0
Apache (worker MPM) + Phusion Passenger          452.10         238.5
Nginx + Mongrel Cluster                          354.80         227.0
Nginx + Thin                                     458.0          228.0
LiteSpeed                                        470.03         334.0
Apache (worker MPM) + Ruby Enterprise
Edition + Phusion Passenger                      564.30         163.5
```

Comment: but more and more developers prefer to use Unicorn now. this is the best choice for today