# What is the role of Apache/nginx in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx

This question is probably obvious, but I don't quite get it yet. To my knowledge a Rails app is deployed by using a web server like Apache or nginx or a cloud provider like Heroku.

What is the responsibility of a webserver like Apache/nginx. Why is the Rails app not simply run on WEBrick only by running `rails server`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webrick as production server vs. Thin or Unicorn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859671/webrick-as-production-server-vs-thin-or-unicorn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it sounds like your question is:

> Q: Why not just use WebBrick as a production server (instead of only
>   for RoR development)?

Here are several good discussions:

- http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/2656
- [Advantages of using Passenger + Apache over Webrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675225/advantages-of-using-passenger-apache-over-webrick)

And from the [Arch Linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ruby_on_Rails):

> While the default Ruby On Rails HTTP server (WeBrick) is convenient
>   for basic development it is not recommended for production use.
>   Generally, you should choose between installing the Phusion Passenger
>   module for your webserver (Apache or Nginx), or use a dedicated
>   application-server (such as Mongrel or Unicorn) combined with a
>   separate web-server acting as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Well not so much. Apparently, it's a more convenient deployment and of course a lot faster. No, the question is more like. What tasks does Apache/nginx fulfill? Do they take in the requests and route them to the Ruby process running the Rails app?

Comment: 1) Ruby is a programming language, 2) Rails is a framework programmed in Ruby, 3) a user interacts with an RoR application via a web browser, and 4) HTTP is the transport used to communicate between the user and the application.  For development purposes, Webbrick is a perfectly good HTTP server.  For production purposes, Apache is often a much better choice.  It's really as simple as that: Apache's "responsibility" is to mediate the HTTP transport layer.

Comment: Q: Is your question answered?  Q: What is the role of Apache/nginx?   A: to provide an HTTP transport between the RoR application and the end user.  Same for webBrick, IIS, and a hundred other alternatives.  Also look at this: [How does PHP interface with Apache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772400/how-does-php-interface-with-apache/2772423#2772423).  The principle is similar for any web server, with any language interpreter (like the Ruby interpreter).  'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably rephrase your question as "why is there a separate web and application tier in Ruby apps?"

In production deployments of Ruby applications there is typically a web tier (e.g. Apache or Nginx) and an application tier (e.g. Unicorn, Thin, Passenger).  The web tier and application tiers serve different purposes:

1. Web tier - Manages HTTP connections, which are potentially persistent and long-lived.  Usually responsible for some configuration of the production deployment (normalizing URLs through rewrites, blocking categories of bad requests, etc.).  Sometimes responsible for HTTPS termination (especially in environments without a load balancer).  Sometimes responsible for serving static assets, a task at which web servers excel.  Most web servers can handle thousands of concurrent requests, with minimal resources needed per request.  So if the web server can handle a request without hitting the app tier, it's strongly preferable for the web server to handle the request.
2. Application tier - Manages requests to the application itself, which usually require some amount of application logic and access to the data storage tier.  Requests are generally expected to be short lived (max a few seconds and ideally a few 10s of msec, Rails Live Streaming excepted).  Concurrency is far more limited in the application tier - most app servers can handle a much smaller number of concurrent requests (1 per process for Thin/Unicorn).

Note this architecture is relatively common to other languages - PHP, Java - as these differentiations largely hold true in systems running those languages as well.

It is possible to run with a unified web and application tier, but that generally requires a system that decouples requests from threads or processes - meaning that one doesn't need a thread or process for each concurrent request.  It adds some complexity to the development side (see Node.js) but can have significant scalability benefits.